# Fazer um botão aparecer depois de determinado tempo

Tags: php, javascript, html

No meu site eu tenho um botão que os clientes pode solicitar uma reposição de seus pedidos. Só que eles usam errado o botão pois estão sempre apertando. Gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de depois de o botão apertado ele sumisse por 24 ou 48h e voltasse a aparecer de novo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<button id="botao" onclick="mudar()">Apertar!</button>

function mudar() {
  /*Comando para sumir com o botão colocando o display como none*/
  document.getElementById("botao").style.display = "none"
  
  /*A função setTimeout diz é a funcão que conta o tempo, no primeiro 
  parâmetro dela você passa ação que vai ocorrer ao final daquele tempo 
  determinado. E no segundo parâmetro você irá passar o tempo em milisegundos.
  10 segundos = 10000 milisegundos
  1 hora = 3600000 milisegundos
  24 horas = 86400000 milisegundos
  48 horas = 172800000 milisegundos*/
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("botao").style.display = "block"
  }, 10000);
}
```